# compare a cell value with column and return result

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare the value of a cell with entire column till there is a data, I'm unable to produce the correct result as only last value from the loop will be placed in the cell and also need to show the count of mis-matched result in other cell.

```
Sub test_blank()
Dim i As Integer, da As Long
da = Range("a2", Range("a15000").End(xlUp)).Count
For i = 1 To da
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("b2").Value Then
        Range("b3") = "match"
    Else
        Range("b3") = "does not match"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to exit the loop after finding a match, or only the last value in column a test is being returned.

Comment: in your code, you are not counting anything

Comment: what kind of a result are you trying to return?

Comment: @jsotola He is counting to whatever the value of `da` is, which I assume is his version of lastrow, however I don't like that method as it's going to return 1 less than what the actual lastrow is.

Comment: @vamsi krishna Make sure to add +1 to your `da` equation to get the real lastrow: `Range("a2", Range("a15000").End(xlUp)).Count + 1`

Comment: `unable to get the count of mis-matched data` - is VBA neccesary? This formula in B3 will give you unmatched data: `=COUNTIF(A2:A15000,"<>"&B2)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the above formula gives the count including the blank cells. I need the result as - "match" or "does not match" in a cell and if does not match, count of the cells which does not match in next cell.

Comment: @vamsikrishna: Are there blank cells in between actual data? Or if at the end of the range? If end of range, simply adjust the last row in the formula.

Comment: ^^ Or use `=COUNTA(A2:A15000)-COUNTIF(A2:A15000,B2)`

Comment: @dwirony, the OP is not counting anything because he is not doing anything with the value of `i`, which is the only variable that increments. evaluating the `Count` property of a range is not counting. also the two variables `i` and `da` are local to the sub, so they will be undeclared outside of the sub

Comment: @jsotola What dwirony was trying to say is that, if the last used cell in column A was cell A100, then `da = Range("a2", Range("a15000").End(xlUp)).Count` (which counts how many cells in that range) is setting `da` to be 99, not to 100 as the OP is probably expecting.  So the `For i` loop is going from `1 To 99` instead of `1 To 100` (which should probably actually be `2 To 100`).  It doesn't resolve the OP's problems, but it is one step in getting there.

Comment: @YowE3K the formula which you gave also works, Thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve could be done like this

```
Sub test_blank()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim doesntMatch As Boolean

    'Set a counter for the number of times it doesn't match
    count = 0
    'Set a flag if a value doesn't match
    doesntMatch = False

    'Go through each cell in the column (starting from A2)
    For Each cell In Range("A2", "A" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        'If the value is found write match and leave the loop
        If (cell <> Range("B2").Value) Then
            doesntMatch = True
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    'If a value didn't match at some point
    If (doesntMatch) Then
        'Display "Doesn't match" and the counter
        Range("B3").Value = "Doesn't match"
        Range("C3").Value = count
    'If always matched
    Else
        'Display "Match"
        Range("B3").Value = "Match"
    End If

End Sub
```

### Logic used

```
Checking every cell
    If the cell doesn't match, increment the counter and activate the flag

If the flag is activated
    Display the message and the counter
If the flag isn't activated
    Display the message
```

Comment: Thats exactly whats happening with my code i.e returning the last value in the loop. But I need the result as "does not match" if any one cell in column A does not match with value to B2 and also the count of the cells which does not match.  As per the code you gave, if the cell A1 matches to B2, it will exit For and results only match in B3.

Comment: Well you should edit your post because none of this is indicated. I'll adapt my code.

Comment: @vamsikrishna I edited my answer, this is doing exactly what you're asking. I display the counter un C3 since you didn't say where you wanted the information ... You can easily adapt it.

Comment: @vamsikrishna Are you saying that the **only** time you want to display "Match" is in the case when **every** cell in column A contains identical values, and that value is also the same as cell B2?

Comment: @Teasel Thankyou for the code, I was actually working on three different workbooks with the data. You helped me. Thankyou very much.